# Getting error when connecting my ether js websocket provider to local node web socket server

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, nodejs, websocket

So I am building my backend to listen for events. So I used the websocket provider of ether js to listen. Since it requires a websocket server url so I built my local websocket server.
But I am getting the error `Error: Unexpected server response: 404`

#### Code of the server

```
var WebSocketServer = require("websocket").server;
var http = require("http");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const port = 8080;

const server = http.createServer(app);

const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
  httpServer: server,
  // You should not use autoAcceptConnections for production
  // applications, as it defeats all standard cross-origin protection
  // facilities built into the protocol and the browser.  You should
  // *always* verify the connection's origin and decide whether or not
  // to accept it.
  autoAcceptConnections: false,
});
wsServer.on("connect", function connection(ws) {
  ws.on("unexpected-response", () => {
    console.log("closed");
    ws.send("data")
  });
  ws.on("error", () => {
    console.log("err");
    ws.send("data")
  });
});

server.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log(new Date() + " Server is listening on port 8080");
});
```

#### Code of the server consuming ether js

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers")
const address = "0x...."
const abi = []

async function main(){
    const provider = new ethers.WebSocketProvider("ws://127.0.0.1:8080")
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(address,abi,provider)
    
    contract.on("FileAdded",(data)=>{
        console.log(data)
    })
}
main()
```